# Is there a reason why my check mark box won't be selected when I click the span tag?

Tags: javascript

```js
//init function
function init() {
  createTaskElements();
}
//create elements and add them to the unordered list
//set attributes
function createTaskElements() {
  const arrChores = ["Walk the dog", "Set dinner table", "Load dishwasher", "Empy Dishwasher", "Clean dinner plates"];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrChores.length; i++) {
    var task = document.createElement("LI");
    task.id = "task";
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.type = "checkbox";
    input.id = "chore";
    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    span.innerHTML = arrChores[i];
    span.addEventListener("click", crossClick);
    task.appendChild(input);
    task.appendChild(span);
    task.addEventListener("click", crossOut);
    document.getElementById("itemsList").append(task);
  }
}
//set the class name of the list item whenever it is clicked to completed
function crossOut() {
  this.className = "completed";
}

function crossClick() {

}
```

[image]

W
hat I want to do when I click the span tag it checks the check box next to the element, but it isn't working.

I know the `.checked` method, but I'm not sure how I would get my function to work.

Comment: Why are you not using the proper element that already comes with the desired functionality, which is a properly attached `label`?

Comment: Use a `<label>` instead of `<span>`, and set `label.htmlFor = input;`

Comment: @Barmar `label.htmlFor = input.id;`

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```js
var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
span.innerHTML = arrChores[i];
```

with

```js
const label = document.createElement("label");
label.textContent = arrChores[i];
label.htmlFor = input.id;
```

You don't need to add any Javascript behaviour to that `label` as it already comes with the functionality you ask for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to.